# Error occurs in saving data in a database and show them in a listview in a Fragment class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I'm developing an android application where it uses a side navigation drawer. In the Fragment class I have an image button and it navigate to a new form to collect user data. After clicks save button, data store in database and display them in a list view in the fragment class where the form creation button is in.

I successfully implement this scenario without using navigation drawer and fragments by following a tutorial. but when I try to implement this using fragment my app stops work. I read the logcat, but I couldn't find any error in those classes.  Please If someone could help me to resolve this problem I really appreciate your help.

This is my Firs Fragment class

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FirstFragment extends ListFragment implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    private View rootView;
    ImageButton btnAccounts;
    TextView getAll;
    TextView student_Id;
    Context context;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);


        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        btnAccounts = rootView.findViewById(R.id.create_account_btn);
        /* btnAccounts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountsType.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }); */

        btnAccounts.setOnClickListener(this);

        getAll = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        getAll.setOnClickListener(this);

            return  rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == view.findViewById(R.id.create_account_btn)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountsType.class);
            intent.putExtra("account_Id", 0);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else {

            AccountRepo repo = new AccountRepo(this);

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> accountList =  repo.getUserList();
            if(accountList.size()!=0) {
                ListView lv = getListView();
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                        student_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_Id);
                        String accountId = student_Id.getText().toString();
                        Intent objIndent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),AccountsType.class);
                        objIndent.putExtra("student_Id", Integer.parseInt( accountId));
                        startActivity(objIndent);
                    }
                });
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),accountList, R.layout.view_account_entry, new String[] { "id","name"}, new int[] {R.id.student_Id, R.id.student_name});
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"No Created Invoices!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

this is the AccountRepo class

```
/**
 * Created by User on 10/10/2017.
 */

public class AccountRepo {

    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public AccountRepo(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public AccountRepo(FirstFragment firstFragment) {
    }

    public int insert(AccountTypesCl account1) {

        //open connection to write data
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(AccountTypesCl.KEY_discount, user1.discount);
        values.put(AccountTypesCl.KEY_code, account1.code);
        values.put(AccountTypesCl.KEY_name, account1.name);
        values.put(AccountTypesCl.KEY_des, account1.des);
        //values.put(User1.KEY_date, user1.date);

        //Inserting row
        long account_Id = db.insert(AccountTypesCl.TABLE, null, values);
        db.close(); //close db connection
        return (int) account_Id;
    }

    public void delete(int account_Id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(AccountTypesCl.TABLE, AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(account_Id)});
        db.close();
    }


    public void update(AccountTypesCl account1) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //values.put(User1.KEY_discount, user1.discount);
        values.put(AccountTypesCl.KEY_code, account1.code);
        values.put(AccountTypesCl.KEY_name, account1.name);
        values.put(AccountTypesCl.KEY_des, account1.des);
        //values.put(User1.KEY_date, user1.date);

        db.update(AccountTypesCl.TABLE, values, AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(account1.Account_ID)});
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getUserList() {
        //Open connection to read only
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  " +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID + "," +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_code + "," +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_name + "," +
               // User1.KEY_discount + "," +
                //User1.KEY_date + "," +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_des +
                " FROM " + AccountTypesCl.TABLE;

        //Student student = new Student();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> account1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                account1.put("id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID)));
                account1.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountTypesCl.KEY_name)));
                userList.add(account1);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return userList;
    }


    public AccountTypesCl getUserById(int Id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  " +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID + "," +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_code + "," +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_name + "," +
                //User1.KEY_discount + "," +
                //User1.KEY_date + "," +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_des +
                " FROM " + AccountTypesCl.TABLE
                + " WHERE " +
                AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID + "=?";// It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string

        int iCount = 0;
        AccountTypesCl account1 = new AccountTypesCl();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(Id)});

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                account1.Account_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID));
                account1.code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountTypesCl.KEY_code));
                account1.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountTypesCl.KEY_name));
                account1.des = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AccountTypesCl.KEY_des));
               // user1.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(User1.KEY_date));
                //user1.value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(User1.KEY_value));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return account1;
    }
}
```

this is the logcat,

```
10-10 13:40:04.563 2853-2853/com.example.user.navigationdrawer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.user.navigationdrawer, PID: 2853
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.navigationdrawer.AccountRepo.getUserList(AccountRepo.java:64)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.navigationdrawer.fragments.FirstFragment.onClick(FirstFragment.java:82)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

new Logcat

```
e.user.navigationdrawer E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: des
10-10 15:15:02.838 2942-2942/com.example.user.navigationdrawer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.user.navigationdrawer, PID: 2942
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.navigationdrawer/com.example.user.navigationdrawer.AccountsType}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: des (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  id,code,name,des FROM Accounts WHERE id=?
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: des (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  id,code,name,des FROM Accounts WHERE id=?
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.navigationdrawer.AccountRepo.getUserById(AccountRepo.java:120)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.navigationdrawer.AccountsType.onCreate(AccountsType.java:51)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

this is the AccountsType class

```
public class AccountsType extends AppCompatActivity {


    Spinner spinner;
    String arraySpinner[];
    TextInputEditText acCode, acName, acType, acDes;
    Button btnSave, btnDelete, btnClose;
    private int _Account_Id = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accounts_type);

        setTitle("Accounts");

        this.arraySpinner = new String[]{
                "Select Account Type", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3", "Type 4", "Type 5"
        };
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerlist);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        acCode = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextAcCode);
        acName = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextAcName);
        acDes = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.textInputEditTextAcAcSed);

        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnClose = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        _Account_Id = 0;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        _Account_Id = intent.getIntExtra("account_Id", 0);
        AccountRepo repo = new AccountRepo(this);
        AccountTypesCl account1 = new AccountTypesCl();
        account1 = repo.getUserById(_Account_Id);

        acCode.setText(account1.code);
        acName.setText(account1.name);
        acDes.setText(account1.des);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.button)) {
            AccountRepo repo = new AccountRepo(this);
            AccountTypesCl account1 = new AccountTypesCl();
            //account1.discount = Integer.parseInt(editTextDiscount.getText().toString());
            account1.code = acCode.getText().toString();
            account1.name = acName.getText().toString();
            //user1.date = txtDate.getText().toString();
            account1.des = acDes.getText().toString();
            account1.Account_ID = _Account_Id;

            if (_Account_Id == 0) {
                _Account_Id = repo.insert(account1);

                Toast.makeText(this, "New Account Insert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                repo.update(account1);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Account Record updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }/* else if (view == findViewById(R.id.button3Delete)) {
            AccountRepo repo = new AccountRepo(this);
            repo.delete(_Account_Id);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Student Record Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            finish(); */ else if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
            finish();
        }

    }

}
```

DBHelper class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_TABLE_ACCOUNT = "CREATE TABLE " + AccountTypesCl.TABLE + "("
                + AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                + AccountTypesCl.KEY_code + " TEXT, "
                + AccountTypesCl.KEY_name + " TEXT, "
                + AccountTypesCl.KEY_type + " TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ACCOUNT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AccountTypesCl.TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your DBHelper class ?

Comment: You're missing the column `AccountTypesCl.KEY_des` when creating your table

Comment: @A.A I add this now, but still app stops work.

Comment: After any changes you make to the database you need to uninstall then reinstall the application to recreate the database

Comment: @A.A Thank you , I uninstall and reinstall the app, now the form opens and can enter data. But data cannot be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the following contructor to create you `AccountRepo` within your fragment

```
public AccountRepo(FirstFragment firstFragment) {
}
```

Try this instead

```
AccountRepo repo = new AccountRepo(getActivity());

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> accountList = repo.getUserList();
```

This way your `DBHelper` won't be null.
Or you can also change the constructor

```
public AccountRepo(FirstFragment firstFragment) {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(firstFragment.getActivity());
}
```

Comment: Which approach did you try? what is the stack trace displaying now?

Comment: I use the second approach , I didn't use spinner values yet

Comment: the new log shows that there is a column 'des' that is not recognized.; may be you added this new one.. in that case you should clear the application's data to recreated you DB

Comment: Thank you as you're trying to help me. But I'm new to android. Can you say the way to clear the applications data.

Comment: You're also missing the column `AccountTypesCl.KEY_des` when creating the table

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing kEY_DESC while creating the table

```
//Here
String CREATE_TABLE_ACCOUNT = "CREATE TABLE " + AccountTypesCl.TABLE + "("
                + AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                + AccountTypesCl.KEY_code + " TEXT, "
                + AccountTypesCl.KEY_name + " TEXT, "
                + AccountTypesCl.KEY_type + " TEXT )";
```

Add Key_desc like this than clear data and reinstall the app

```
String CREATE_TABLE_ACCOUNT = "CREATE TABLE " + AccountTypesCl.TABLE + "("
                    + AccountTypesCl.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                    + AccountTypesCl.KEY_code + " TEXT, "
                    + AccountTypesCl.KEY_name + " TEXT, "
                    + AccountTypesCl.KEY_des + " TEXT, "
                    + AccountTypesCl.KEY_type + " TEXT )";
```

Comment: I add it, Now I can open the form, but still I cannot save data.

Comment: debug and check getUserList() method that weather your are getting account_id value -1 or greater than -1

Comment: By the way the issue mention in the question is resolved